# how to solve run time error of The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -43.)?

Tags: objective-c

I am beginner of iPhone. I want to play audio.for that purpose I have used AVAudioPlayer.. but that object return null value.. and also give run time error of The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -43.)

This is the code I used

```
-(IBAction)sound
{
   NSError *error;
   int currentsound;
    path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Animalfile" ofType:@"plist"];
    dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

    animalaudio=[dict valueForKey:@"audio"];
    NSLog(@"print:%@",dict);
    NSLog(@"printanimal%@",animalaudio);
    audiolist=[animalaudio objectAtIndex:currentsound];
    NSLog(@"audiolist:%@",audiolist);
    url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:audiolist];
    NSLog(@"url:%@",url);
     audioplayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    NSLog(@"audioplayer:%@",audioplayer);
     if( audioplayer == nil ){

        NSLog(@"Failed with reason: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else{
        [audioplayer play];
    }
  }
```

in that url also return the mp3 file but why url not pass in AVAudioPlayer because of audioplayer return the null but not return mp3 file.so, which code I write in AVAudioPlayer?give any suggestion and source code....

Answer (score 0):

```
path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Animalfile" ofType:@"plist"];
```

path must be a single file not a plist

try to give the path one value

Example:

```
path = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"firstTrack" ofType:@"mp3"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

-43 is a File not found error
Check that the relative file path in your plist can be found from the working directory.
Or better, use one of the many resource-finding methods of NSBundle to find your sound file directly, you will then get an existing absolute path.